# copy and paste in windows XP just stops working

Tags: windows-xp, clipboard

out of nowhere my copy and paste just stops working.  has anyone seen this happening.  is there any recommended way of debugging what is going on and any solutions to fix it?

Comment: Are you using Remote Desktop to connect to another machine? The rdpclip.exe process is notorious for causing problems with the clipboard.

Comment: same problem, even if I copy paste from menu, so it's not just the Ctrl-C/V shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What I found:](http://www.howtofixcomputers.com/bb/ftopic140408.html)

> This has to do with some application
>   that's having a lock over the Windows 
>   Clipboard. David Candy's application
>   should determine the Process that's 
>   causing the problem.
>
> Download GetOpenClipboardWindow.zip
>   from here: 
>   [> http://windowsxp.mvps.org/temp/GetOpenClipboardWindow.zip](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/temp/GetOpenClipboardWindow.zip)
>
> Unzip and run the tool. Post back what
>   it reports. For best results, run 
>   this utility during the time you
>   encounter the Copy<=>Paste problem.

So it might be some program is locking your Clipboard. Try to find out what's causing the problem and let us know.

Comment: I know for sure that remote desktop does that quite often

Comment: that fixed the problem for me! I was using TeamViewer as a client to connect to different machine. But not even closing the TeamViewer (which was already logged off when that problem started) solved the problem. Running this program did!!

Answer (score 0):

I've had programs cause my Ctrl key to be "stuck" such as if I am using Synergy and move my mouse off the screen while the Ctrl key is down.

It is also possible you have Sticky keys enabled that is causing something similar(if so, hit the right side Ctrl key will "release the ctrl key again, and then go into your Accessibility settings in windows and disable sticky keys)

Comment: Is this the issue you're talking about? http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=9

Comment: this is not necessarily connected to the Ctrl-C/V shortcut, for me it is not working even if I copy/paste from menu