# Why does Ctrl+C randomly stop working in Microsoft Office?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I've lost count of the number of times I've pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy something in some Microsoft Office app, flipped to another window or app, pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste, and instead, it pastes whatever had previously been in the clipboard. Annoyed, I flip back to the previous window, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again, flip, paste, still doesn't work. Sometimes I have to try this three or four times.

Why does Office do this? It's like it's responding to keyboard shortcuts sluggishly, forcing me to slow down for something I shouldn't have to slow down for, making it generally irritating to use.

I haven't noticed this behavior in any other program. I can't remember if it's happened prior to the 2013 version. I've definitely had it happen in PowerPoint and Word.

It isn't [simply stopping](https://superuser.com/questions/145268/copy-paste-stops-working-on-windows-7). It will stop, and then maybe start again. And then stop again. And start again. (Hence, "randomly".) I don't use Notepad++. I have Skype up, but if it were truly interfering with keyboard shortcuts, it wouldn't suddenly stop interfering. I might try the clipboard lock monitor when I get home, but I can't use it at work. Does it constantly monitor the lock in real time? If it doesn't, it won't be useful to diagnose this problem unless I'm extremely lucky.

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't have access to that app here, sadly.

Comment: When the problem occurs, have you tried copying out of another program to confirm the problem is isolated to Office programs?

Comment: Per the final paragraph, it seems that OP has read the suggested 'duplicate' and neither the circumstances nor the fixes apply.

Comment: If none of the existing answers apply and this is a random event, troubleshooting the problem will be out of scope, and answers will likely be speculation.

Comment: @fixer1234 Fair point, but that still doesn't mean this is a duplicate.

Comment: Most of the duplicate votes were already there before bertieb posted the observation.  I commented and voted to close based on it being too broad.  The system often aggregates reasons when it posts the close notice.  It also treats "duplicate" as more specific than other reasons and links it as a duplicate if 3 or 4 votes were that reason and the others were more general.  At this point, it is a question of what will be most useful to searchers landing here.  If it is closed as too broad, it is a dead end.  As a duplicate, some readers will be linked to something potentially helpful to them.

Comment: @Twisty Next time this manifests, I'll try copying from a web browser (I often have both Chrome and Firefox up) and report what happens.

Comment: I have similar issue without MS Office installed. I suppose it is related to Windows 10 not the Office

Comment: At the time I reported this, I was still on Windows 7 (Home Edition). I've since upgraded to 10. I haven't seen it again... yet. But then, I've hardly used Word in the last two years.

Comment: I think I've had this happen with Microsoft Teams as well.

Answer (score 4):

MS Office 2013/2016 have [multi-clipboard feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-and-paste-multiple-items-by-using-the-Office-Clipboard-714a72af-1ad4-450f-8708-c2931e73ec8a), triggered when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> twice. This allows you to copy up to 24 multiple items. You can disable this feature:

1. Select the *Home* tab.
2. Select the arrow next to *Clipboard*.
3. Select *Options* at the bottom-left of the window.
4. Unselect *Show Office Clipboard When CTRL+C Pressed Twice*
   [Control how the Office Clipboard is displayed](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-and-paste-multiple-items-by-using-the-Office-Clipboard-714a72af-1ad4-450f-8708-c2931e73ec8a)

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with a multi-clipboard feature. Destructive as the default feature is, Ctrl+C pressed once ought to overwrite the current clipboard as always, not behave sporadically.

Comment: I have similar issue, and it's stop after disable this feature.

Comment: This fixed the issues I had with Ctrl+C / Ctrl-V not working. Thanks!