# How to disable OneNote losing my clipboard when I exit the app?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

I'm using the OneNote integrated to Windows 10.

This is happening every day:

- I copy something I need
- Exit OneNote
- Paste doesn't work (because I have forgotten about the bug again)
- I restart OneNote
- I copy again
- I minimize OneNote
- I paste what I needed
- I go back to OneNote
- I exit it

It is 100% abnormal to lose clipboard content on exit, why is MS doing it? I guess it is "by design" to annoy people? **I cannot find any option to disable it. But maybe there is a Windows or hidden or registry setting?**

Since it is abnormal (Microsoft Visual Studio or Microsoft Edge, for example, are NOT doing this, obviously or any other app I know) I'm rather stop using OneNote than to form a new habit, and waste my time to go back twice just to exit.

I don't understand why Microsoft keep making obviously bad design decisions that are **inconsistent** even with their own apps...

Comment: Maybe turning on clipboard history (e.g., by pressing Win+V) or installing a clipboard content manager (like Ditto Clipboard) will make sure that some program grabs the clipboard contents before OneNote exits.

Comment: Is this related? https://superuser.com/questions/145268/copy-paste-stops-working-on-windows-7