# My copy & paste no longer works on my laptop

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [copy and paste in windows XP just stops working](https://superuser.com/questions/18814/copy-and-paste-in-windows-xp-just-stops-working)

I have already done full AV and malware scans and I am clear.  Using mouse right-click and/or keyboard commands it gives me the option to copy but than it either does not paste or the paste command is grayed out.  This happens in IE-9 and Word.  I am running Windows 7 64 bit.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a few people have experienced problems with this and a possible fix, although not ideal, is to disable Aero.  To do this, follow these steps:

1. Right-click the desktop and select **Personalize**.
2. Under where it says **Basic and High Contrast Themes**, set the theme to **Windows Classic**.
3. You may need to reboot for this to work.

Obviously if you'd like to save your current theme beforehand, then do so.  I have no idea why this would work but I know someone who had this issue and this solved it for them.  Give it a shot and let us know.