# Can't Copy/Paste Files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

Starting yesterday, after I installed the Windows Updates I can no longer copy/paste files on my system.

I can however, copy and paste text just fine.

Both keyboard and mouse copy/paste functions are not working, the **Paste** option is always grayed out.

I have tried restarting explorer.exe, rdpclip.exe and running `sfc /scannow` to no avail. Anybody have any other suggestions?

Windows 7 Pro SP1 - 64bit

Comment: Have you tried and actual reboot of the machine yet?  Does it work as epxected if you boot into Safe Mode? have you seen/tried [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/18832/23133) yet?

Comment: Yes, rebooted several times. And that's the first I've seen of that tool, it reported no problems. Thanks though, that's a great find!

Comment: *Does it work as expected if you boot into Safe Mode?* :)

Comment: Yes, just got done doing that and it works as expected in Safe Mode. Booted back up normal, now it's back to not working :/

Comment: [See this page](http://www.ctimls.com/Support/KB/Error%20Fixes/Fix_Clipboard_Issues.htm)

Answer (score 2):

> it works as expected in Safe Mode

If it works in Safe Mode then it's most likely a 3rd party start-up program or service that's causing it.

Use Windows' [MSConfig](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/using-system-configuration#1TC=windows-7) to disable all 3rd party start-ups and services, and see if Copy and Paste works.

If it does, then (using MSConfig) re-enable each thing, one at a time (and reboot) until you figure out which one is causing your grief.

Once you've figured out what it is, then you can decide how you want to deal with it (eg: uninstall the problematic program).

Comment: I disabled all services and startups and still didn't work. Did a system restore to last week and now it's working....very strange.

Comment: Interesting.  Bad driver then perhaps(?).

Answer (score 1):

Net information suggests that the failure of Windows Explorer and My Computer to copy/paste files under W7 results from some problem involving Internet Explorer.

But going straight to Internet Explorer (version 11.0.9600.18537 Update version 11.0.38 KB3203621) will also access the standard Windows Explorer screen. To locate your original file, use File/ Open/ Browse to navigate to the file's folder and then change IE's default file type from Web Documents to whatever file type is being searched for.

Then the traditional right-click 'copy' command on the selected file in one folder enables a duplicate to be transferred to the destination folder and deposited with the right-click 'paste' command.

There is also an option to start Internet Explorer without Add-ons (under menu/ Accessories/ System Tools) but this step wasn't necessary. The version of Windows Explorer was 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) for Windows 7 Home Premium and this evidently has some compatibility problem with Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Can you provide some links to the resources you found online about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for us: Uninstall update KB3057839 (6-09-2015 and on). That fixed the issue. You may have to, although highly unrecommended, turn off automatic updates altogether because the next day, another set of updates caused the same issue.

Comment: As a general rule, I don't look kindly to any suggestion for disabling Windows Update without evidence to support it. OP says it works okay in Safe Mode, so Windows itself is not to blame.

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround, having unsucessfully tried all the other suggestions (running sfc /scannow multiple times, updating video driver, running virus scan, and running in safe mode).

Open a file in MS Word, click save as.  When the dialogue box opens select a file you want to move in the left hand folder tree section, click and drag it to your desired location and hey presto file/folder moved.

Comment: Can't you just drag and drop between two Explorer windows opened side by side?